# Onclick button doesn't work asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a login form with two fields .. email and password fields, and one button to login. 
At first, the codes behind the login button was working perfectly.. then, I left this website aside to work on another project, after awhile, I ran it again in my laptop using "Admin" account but actually i didn't try to press on login button.
however, now i'm running the website on "MY" account and the login button is not working at all, while it was before as i said !!! 
I searched for solutions over Internet, but none of them helped ! One of the solutions i implemented was to create new web form and add the codes again, but still the same thing! the login button is not working but it doesn't show any error messages.

this is my code:

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string email = Request.Form["Email"];
        string pass = Request.Form["Password"];


        if (email == "" || pass == "")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert(' Enter your email and password please ')", true);
            return;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select CountryName from AdministratorsEnglish where AdminEmail = @adminEmail and AdminPassword = @adminPassword", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adminEmail", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adminPassword", pass);
        con.Open();
        countryName = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());



        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        //If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
        if (count == 1)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert(' Welcome again ! ')", true);
            Session["CountryName"] = countryName;
            Server.Transfer("MainPageEng.aspx", true);

        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert(' You have enetered wrong information ')", true);
        }
    }
```

And this the html:

```
<form class="login-form" >
    <input type="text" placeholder="email" id="emailtxt" name="Email"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="passwordtxt" name="Password"/>
      <%--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style3" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="Login" BackColor="Red" />--%>
    <button id="loginbtn" runat="server" onserverclick="Button2_Click1">login</button>

  </form>
```

I need help please !!!

Comment: debug?or put a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace your HTML Part with Following :

```
<div class="login-form">
        <asp:TextBox ID="emailtxt" runat="server" placeholder="email"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="passwordtxt" runat="server" TextMode="Password" placeholder="password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="loginbtn" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click1" Text="login"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: well, it worked .. but the theme has changed to the default, thanks anyway

Comment: you can now add the css class accordingly